# On Silverstripe, how can we auto publish child pages if rearrange?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm trying to auto publish child pages if they are rearrange. Right now when we arrange those child pages it says `modified`.

We're trying to achieve an automation on how to auto publish it once we started drag and drop to their position.

Answer (score 0):

The idea may be to check the change of the Sort field and execute the `doPublish()`. Please, note that you must check if the page wasn't in the Draft state.

```php
class FooPage extends Page {

    private $wasPublishedBeforeWrite = false;

    protected function onBeforeWrite()
    {
        parent::onBeforeWrite();
        // check if the page is published
        $this->wasPublishedBeforeWrite = !$this->isArchived() && !$this->isOnDraftOnly() && !$this->isModifiedOnDraft();
    }

    protected function onAfterWrite()
    {
        parent::onAfterWrite();
        if ($this->isChanged('Sort') && $this->wasPublishedBeforeWrite) {
            $this->publishSingle();
        }
    }
}
```